# Is this a bijection function?

Tags: functions, modular-arithmetic

Why is this not a bijection, one-to-one, nor onto function?

$f(x) = x^{3}\space mod\space 21$

Can anyone give me a full explanation on this? Thanks.

Comment: What's the intended domain? I assume the codomain is meant to be $\Bbb Z/(21)$, but one cannot deduce injectivity, surjectivity, or bijectivity without knowing where the function maps from and to.

Comment: @Not an easy question please see my answer,you need  example of two set in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one to one means that if $f(x)=f(y)$ this implies that $x=y$

now take $x=21$ and $y=42$

$f(x)=f(y)$ but  $x$ does not equal to $y$

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection

you can search formation on bijection and also  onto

http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/algtrig/ATP5/OntoFunctions.htm

for onto there is written that

A function f from A to B is called onto if for all b in B there is an a in A such that f (a) = b.   All elements in B are used.

but please above terminology works properly we we know what  amount of $x$ we have and what amount of  $x^3 mod 21$ we have ,if it is all the $x$,then no problem,but

you say about range of $x$?first example about  one-to-one  works for all continuous $x$,but may fail in some specific range of $x$,so please tell us exactly  range of $x$